# Does the dot product angle formula work for $\Bbb{R}^n$?

Tags: vectors, products

Whenever I have seen this formula discussed

\begin{equation}
\textbf{A} \cdot \textbf{B} = \|\textbf{A} \| \|\textbf{B} \| \cos\theta
\end{equation}
I have always seen it using vectors in $\Bbb{R}^2$.

I was wondering if this property works if $\dim \textbf{A}= \dim \textbf{B} = n$. I feel like it wouldn't because for spherical coordinates we need more than one angle. We use $\phi$ and $\theta$. But I have no idea. Maybe I am confusing the meaning of $\theta$ in the dot product angle formula. It isn't a dimension right?

**My Question:**

Does the dot product angle formula apply to $\Bbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Actually, this is used as the *definition* of angle in higher $n$

Comment: I think this comment is my favorite response. If you care to make it into an answer, I would accept it. Question: I have been studying Riemannian geometry and the books I use discuss metric tensors. They say they metric tensors can be used to define lengths and angle between tangent vectors. Is this the formula used for the latter?  That is, if we have some notion of length from our metric tensor, we can presumably use this definition of angle to find the angle between tangent vectors at a point on a manifold. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Yes it does. It says so on the metric tensor Wikipedia article. Cool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does. If you accept that this holds in $\mathbb R^2$, the fact that it holds in $\mathbb R^n$ follows fairly easily - notice that for any choice of two vectors $A$ and $B$, it is always possible to choose a two-dimensional subspace (i.e. a plane) containing both vectors (the span of the two vectors usually functions), and the dot product on this subspace is the same as in $\mathbb R^2$ - so we're measuring the angle between $A$ and $B$ *as if* they were just two dimension vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It does. The inner product is defined in n space in linear algebra. https://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Euclidean_space.html. You should also read the wikipedia article on inner product.